# CiviDiscount "Specify api string for advanced filter"

Tags: api, cividiscount

I'd like to use CiviDiscount to create an automatic discount based on a custom data field on the contact record.

Looking at the options for the Automatic Discount, there is a field called "Specify api string for advanced filter" but when I put a value into this field and save, it isn't actually saved. I'm not sure if this is because the strong is wrong, or something else.

I was testing with a group value as this using the same advanced value that is used when creating contact reference fields:

action=get&group=532

Answer (score 2):

There is an example here: https://github.com/dlobo/org.civicrm.module.cividiscount/blob/master/README.md

You need to specify the entity and format the api string as JSON.